# Showing that the rank of the complex projective space is 1

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

I was assigned the task of calculating the rank of the complex projective space $\mathbb C P^n=SU(n)/S(U(1)\times U(n-1))$ and am not sure how best to approach that task. (looking in the classification of symmetric spaces does not count as calculating)

I considered using the fact that the sectional curvature is 
$$
sec(z,w)=1+3|Im \langle w,z\rangle|>0
$$
For any $z,w\in T_p(\mathbb C P^n)$ as proven in "Riemannian Geometry" by Peter Petersen (pp.222-224, Chapter 8.2.3) and then concluding that this implies that each totally geodesic submanifold has nonzero curvature and is therefore either one-dimensional or not flat.

I am not sure if that conclusion is correct and would like hints as to where I can find more information. If it is indeed incorrect, why is it? And what is a better way to prove it?

Comment: Your discussion implies that your definition of rank is that it's the maximal $k$ such that every geodesic is contained in a $k$-dimensional totally geodesic isometrically embedded $\mathbb{R}^k$, or at least that you know this property of rank for symmetric spaces, in which case I don't see anything wrong with this argument.

Comment: @mollyerin Thank you very much for your response. I have put some effort into double-checking this and I am almost certain that this proof is correct. (it, more or less, has to be)